Caused By: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory
I have upgraded the logback-core and logback-classic jar from 1.0.11 version to the 1.3.12. My project also using logback-ext.spring-0.1.1 , which is causing the below issue while restarting the application.
listener defined in the web.xml :
<listener>
        <listener-class>ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.web.LogbackConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

Caused By: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, ch/qos/logback/ext/spring/LogbackConfigurer, and the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/GenericClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
        at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.LogbackConfigurer.initLogging(LogbackConfigurer.java:72)
        at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.web.WebLogbackConfigurer.initLogging(WebLogbackConfigurer.java:142)
        at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.web.LogbackConfigListener.contextInitialized(LogbackConfigListener.java:54)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:719)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1929)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3191)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1864)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:919)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)

I have tried updating the logback-ext.spring-0.1.1 to logback-ext.spring-0.1.5

Does this answer your question? SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". error

you have two different org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory class files in your classpaths

Does this answer your question? SLF4J error: class loader have different class objects for the type

As I was looking for the alternative for listener provided by the  logback-ext.spring, I end up creating the custom listener same as provided by the lib.
